# Default content-type for Django test client

Tags: django, testing, client

I am trying to make `application/json` the default content type of the Django test client.

I am wondering if there is a smarter way than this:

```
from functools import partial

c = Client()
c.post = partial(c.post, content_type="application/json")
```

I tried `Client(content_type="application/json")` and `Client(HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE="application/json")` but neither of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass `APITestCase` and set `client_class` to your own subclassed version of `APIClient`. This would be better than monkey-patching, in my opinion.